# Distinguishing between "speaks [like]" and "leave [something behind | out]"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

How can I distinguish between:

> 1. He speaks like father
> 2. He speaks as a father

because really this confuses me.

---

How to distinguish between three sentences and the tips

> 1. He left the umbrella behind
> 2. He left out the last word in the sentence
> 3. He left the house

Comment: This should really be split into two questions.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. We encourage you to ask questions here, but please read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages, and also our [**Details, Please**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post. They will help you write a better question. Ask one question at a time, please!

Answer (score 1):

> He speaks like father

The gentleman in question reminds you of *your* father when he speaks.

> He speaks as a father

The gentleman in question is speaking from the point of view of his *personal experience* of being a father, not necessarily *yours*.

---

> To leave something behind

To forget something

> To leave something out

To omit something, a detail, a piece of information<sup>1</sup>

> To leave

To exit (a room, building, a situation, etc.)

---

<sup>1</sup> To leave something out, can also mean to forget to bring something indoors:

> He left the saw out, and then it got rusty in the rain.